# Possible extra term in the Gauss-Bonnet Action

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, curvature, spacetime-dimensions

Is it possible to add a term like $\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}R^{\alpha\beta}_{\enspace\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu\gamma\delta}$ to the Gauss-Bonnet action in higher dimensional theories of gravity? Or can this term be expressed as a linear combination of $R^2$, $R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}$ and $R_{\nu\mu\rho\sigma}R^{\nu\mu\rho\sigma}$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Epsilon symbol with 4 indices exist only in 4d. I think, that in 4d this term really expressed as a linear combination